# Right justify the 5 bits 29-25 and zero extend. mips/assembly

Tags: mips

Currently working on a school project were we are converting a high level programming language to a low level programming language.

n := [right-justify the five bits "seed"<29:25>, and zero-extend];

Where seed is  0x6afdcda8

The way I have attempted to receive the bits 29-25 is by doing this.

```
sll $t0, $s0, 2
srl $t0,$t0,25
```

Is this a correct way to do this? What about the zero extend part?

Comment: The zero-extention happens automatically, since you're getting rid of the initial two most-significant bits and then using a logical right shift. Although shoudn't the shift amount for the `srl` be 27 (25+2)?

Comment: @Michael thank you.